# Map user locations lat/long on google places api for app

Tags: android, google-places-api

Hi I have a question regarding the google places API for a dev project I am working on.

Users will have the ability to plot a place they have been anywhere in their city. I would like the map (in the app) to show the pin for this location for other users to see. Could someone help me find the documentation or if google places api is the right choice for this scenario?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could would be to cache all of the users locations from their maps and then redraw the markers from there.

In most cases the act of caching user location data and sharing that data with other users is heavily restricted under the [9.3 End User Terms and Privacy Policy](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_3) section of [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)